# AngularJS: How to set a style attribute for all elements?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a form page that I'm working on and the basic AngularJS structure is working. When the user selects a particular font, I want all page elements to change to that font. In my stylesheet, I am using the "*" selector but I can't figure out how to update that via Angular. I have attached the basic page structure code below (note that the page has more elements than this but I removed all but the H1 for this question). Any ideas?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="theapp">
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 12pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="FormController as form">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <form name="theForm">
        <select ng-model="font" ng-options="font.face for font in fonts"></select>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            angular.module("theapp", [])
                .controller("FormController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.fonts = [
                        { face: "sans-serif" },
                        { face: "Arial" },
                        { face: "Tahoma" },
                        { face: "Trebuchet MS" },
                        { face: "Verdana" },
                        { face: "serif" },
                        { face: "Times" },
                        { face: "Georgia" },
                        { face: "monospace" },
                        { face: "Courier" }
                    ];
                    $scope.font = $scope.fonts[0];
                }]);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [orange] and [nilsK] for your suggestions.
Both are good ideas but still don't do quite what I need.
In the end, I decided to just use jQuery to update the $("*").css() attribute.
(We're already using jQuery anyway so I'm not bringing in another JS library unnecessarily.)
This does exactly what I need and doesn't complicate the code.
Thanks again! :)

Comment: Can you explain what didn't work with the approaches we proposed?

Comment: I guess I should have been more verbose with my sample code above. We actually have 3 controllers on the page, one at the body level that is actually not the FormController as indicated. We don't want to mix the functionality of the controllers so the solution you provide -- although it works -- won't work for us. The main issue I was trying to resolve was how to address the $("*") selector via AngularJS. It doesn't appear Angular can easily handle that but jQuery can. (If you know of a way for Angular to address the * selector, please let me know.) Thanks again.

Comment: The Angular way is not to do any DOM manipulation imperatively, but to markup those simple changes in the template (as shown). Even if you have 3 controllers this would work, as scopes inherit parent scope's properties (unless they are isolated as in a directive).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-style` in your markup and link it to the `scope.font` variable.

Have a look at the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

I haven't tried it, but you could add a `div` under the `body` such that `<div ng-style="style">` and in your controller you do `$scope.style = {"font-family": $scope.font}`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="font-family:{{font.face}}"` to the body tag.
I made a [plunkr to demonstrate](http://plnkr.co/edit/hlG9XTGCSstI2MdXAhJI?p=preview)